# How to store a list of unique partition keys within my DynamoDb table?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with a composite primary key (partition and sort keys). I want to get a list of the unique partition keys within my DB. I understand I can't query for this, so I have to store this info somewhere as records are being added to the DB. anyone got any tips on how to go about doing this?

I was thinking of keeping a JSON or txt file in an S3 bucket and updating it with new unique partition keys as records are inserted to the DDB. Trying to avoid a scan operation as it is suboptimal performance-wise.

Comment: Why do you need this? How much data and what insertion rate?

Comment: You can create another DynamoDB table with just partition key as primary key. Now, whenever you insert a new record in main table, also put one record in other table.  Or you could use DynamoDB triggered Lambda for insertion into another table. However this approach is not good if you have higher insertion rate.

Comment: You probably want to re-think your use case for Dynamo if you need a list of all your PKs. Generally this is not a good practice and will not be scalable. What is your use case for needing all these? At the very least you will want to rethink how you are storing the data in dynamo (schema).